# PHP API Call with Httpful and Basic Auth Header

Tags: php, authentication, httpful

I am using [Httpful](http://phphttpclient.com/) to call an API that uses basic authentication headers.

Here is how my GET request is set up:

```
<?php
include('httpful.phar');

$uri = "https://example.com";
$response = \Httpful\Request::get($uri)
    ->addHeader('Authorization', 'Basic KEY')
    ->send();
echo $response;
?>
```

This works correctly and I am able to display the response data on my PHP page.

However, is this the most secure way to add headers using basic auth? Should I be placing the auth key into a separate file or something more secure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Should I be placing the auth key into a separate file

Probably. As a general rule, you should never commit authentication credentials to your source repository. So, if this file is source controlled, I'd pull out the hard-coded value and replace it with a variable.

How you set that variable depends on your environment. Often it's sufficient to read from a JSON, INI, or YML config file. Just make sure you set your .gitignore (or equivalent) to exclude that config file from the repository, and make sure that the file is **outside** the web server's document root, so that it can not be read directly.

Note, if you've *already* committed the key, then you'll want to change it, as its current value will live forever in your repository history.